# sequentially should load data in viewpager fragments and the previous tabs view should be visible on switching back

Tags: android

I am using using viewpager to show 10 different fragments data at once.i used `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);` to load all fragments data at once.But the issue is its taking a lot time to load the data .I want to load the data of particular tab which iam and the data should not be destroyed when i switch over to that tab again.